# How to set-up/enable Fingerprint sensor?

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my HP dm4-2180 laptop. I wanted to know if there is a way to enable/set-up the Fingerprint sensor. I read through a few related thread and understand that not all make and models have Fingerprint plugins available yet. The `lsusb` command yields following result:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0018 Validity Sensors, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 10f1:1a2e Importek
```

Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output of the lsusb you provided, I am not sure that your finger printer scanner is supported (device id: 138a:0018 doesn't show up in the the supported devices list).

in any case, there is a package you can install that will work with supported finger print scanners:

1. Add this PPA to your sources:
     sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fingerprint/fprint
     sudo apt-get update
     sudo apt-get upgrade
2. Install the software:
    sudo apt-get install libfprint0 fprint-demo libpam-fprintd gksu-polkit

You can find more detailed information at:
https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fprint

Hope that helps!